# Is there a word in English to describe "the pain of watching somebody else perform an action incorrectly"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, watching somebody use the wrong tool for a task, organizing items in the wrong order, etc. A perfect example of a scenario that may elicit this emotion is the ["wrong block" meme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=9nSQs0Gr9FA). I have tried googling but can't find any word for this.

Example sentence:

> I experienced *word* while watching a new mechanic using the wrong tool to remove a bolt, while the right tool was lying next to them in their toolkit. Had they used the correct tool, it would have been removed in half the time and without stripping the bolt in the process.

Comment: "...the right tool was _lying_...", please!

Comment: @KateBunting I have seen to it.

Comment: [correction: I **heard the word** etc.] By the way, this happens all the time on SE's English sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from Anton's suitable suggestion of frustration, I think '[cringe](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cringe)' is more specific (and I *feel* it's used more often these days for exactly the kinds of experiences you describe):

> to feel very embarrassed or awkward; react with discomfort:
> *Some of us cringed at the speaker’s tactless comments.*

It's usually used as a verb, but can be used as a noun as well:

> an instance of being very embarrassed, awkward, or uncomfortable:
> *Some of his outfits are bizarre enough to induce a cringe or two.*

In your example: "*I cringed (/experienced cringe) while watching a new mechanic using the wrong tool to remove a bolt, while the right tool was laying next to them in their toolkit.*"

Comment: It seems to me cringe is more of a description of the reaction (similar to wince) as opposed to the emotional experience, but I think this is the best word for this nonetheless.

Comment: _Cringe_ was voted one of the top ten most over-used words for the year. See:https://www.thetoptens.com/internet/overused-annoying-words-online/

Answer (score 2):

In some contexts you may be said to experience **exasperation**. It applies particularly when you are unable or not permitted to interfere with the person’s activity.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exasperation)
> *exasperation* noun:
> the feeling of being annoyed, especially because you can do nothing to solve a problem.

Having given responsibility to the garage for the job you felt exasperation (were exasperated) on seeing the incompetent mechanic at work.

You may also feel **frustration**.

> [longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/frustration)
> *frustration* noun
> the feeling of being annoyed, upset, or impatient, because you cannot control or change a situation, or achieve something

In both cases you know how the job should be done but cannot do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To wince or to flinch is to recoil when seeing something that upsets us, surprises us, or makes us feel uncomfortable.

> I winced while watching a new mechanic using the wrong tool . . ..

Or,

> I flinched while watching a new mechanic using the wrong tool . . ..

The former word would evince a telling facial expression that conveys discomfort, perhaps from witnessing cringe-worthy behavior.

[image]

The latter word, in addition to the  would likely evince a lifting of the shoulders and a tensing of the neck muscles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the emotion is a feeling of grief rather than anger, consider **commiseration**.

> If you are feeling commiseration for someone, he is probably going
> through difficult times. We feel commiseration when others suffer or
> feel pain and we understand that pain. Commiserate with them, we
> express our sympathy.
> (*source : https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/commiseration*)

The reason for that feeling is general, i.e. not specifically related to the ineptitude of someone.